# google ads api - "argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'"

Tags: python, google-ads-api, google-api-python-client

I've been trying to follow the examples and documentation for the python ad_manager library for the google ads API, but I haven't been able to complete a successful request. I currently have my developer token, client_id, client_secret, and refresh_token in my google ads YAML file, but I'm constantly getting the error "argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'" when calling the function WaitForReport following the example code below. I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how I could tackle this issue.

```py
import tempfile

# Import appropriate modules from the client library.
from googleads import ad_manager
from googleads import errors


def main(client):
  # Initialize a DataDownloader.
  report_downloader = client.GetDataDownloader(version='v202111')

  # Create report job.
  report_job = {
      'reportQuery': {
          'dimensions': ['COUNTRY_NAME', 'LINE_ITEM_ID', 'LINE_ITEM_NAME'],
          'columns': ['UNIQUE_REACH_FREQUENCY', 'UNIQUE_REACH_IMPRESSIONS',
                      'UNIQUE_REACH'],
          'dateRangeType': 'REACH_LIFETIME'
      }
  }

  try:
    # Run the report and wait for it to finish.
    report_job_id = report_downloader.WaitForReport(report_job)
  except errors.AdManagerReportError as e:
    print('Failed to generate report. Error was: %s' % e)

  # Change to your preferred export format.
  export_format = 'CSV_DUMP'

  report_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.csv.gz', delete=False)

  # Download report data.
  report_downloader.DownloadReportToFile(
      report_job_id, export_format, report_file)

  report_file.close()

  # Display results.
  print('Report job with id "%s" downloaded to:\n%s' % (
      report_job_id, report_file.name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Initialize client object.
  ad_manager_client = ad_manager.AdManagerClient.LoadFromStorage()
  main(ad_manager_client)
```

Edit:
Below is the stack trace:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleads/common.py", line 984, in MakeSoapRequest
    return soap_service_method(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zeep/proxy.py", line 46, in __call__
    return self._proxy._binding.send(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 135, in send
    return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 229, in process_reply
    return self.process_error(doc, operation)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 317, in process_error
    raise Fault(
zeep.exceptions.Fault: Unknown fault occured

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_ads.py", line 72, in <module>
    main(ad_manager_client)
  File "google_ads.py", line 33, in main1
    report_job_id = report_downloader.WaitForReport(report_job)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleads/ad_manager.py", line 784, in WaitForReport
    report_job_id = service.runReportJob(report_job)['id']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleads/common.py", line 989, in MakeSoapRequest
    underlying_exception = e.detail.find(
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
```

Comment: can you post the *exact* stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: Sure! I updated the post with the exact stacktrace that I'm getting.

Comment: @EdmondPoon did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your YAML file, do you have your account number in quotes? (either single or double?)

Additionally, I would highly recommend not going with this API if you have the option. It will be sunset in April and will no longer work. The newer google ads API (as opposed to the AdWords API) is available, stable and much easier to work with. The ad manager examples are good too.

Comment: I don’t use any quotes in my yaml file. Are they suppose to be in quotes? I’ve also been trying out the ad manager examples (the code mentioned above is one of the examples), but I’m still encountering the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `zeep` [raises a WebFault which includes the returned XML response as a string in `zeep.Fault.detail`](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/2f35b7d29355ba646f5e3c6e9925033d5d6df8bb/src/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py#L317).

Somewhat counter-intuitive, this attribute is **not** a string, but a bytes sequence [because `zeep.wsdl.utils.etree_to_string` calls `etree.tostring()` with `encoding="utf-8"`](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/f497b78cbec01bb6718eec24fbbca4f596863ca8/src/zeep/wsdl/utils.py#L27) instead of `encoding="unicode"`—[the latter would make sure it's a proper string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring).

`googleads` then tries to look for specific error strings inside the XML using `find()`, but even though `find()` is defined both on `str` and `bytes`, the type of the substring to look for needs to align.

Thus, in

```python
underlying_exception = e.detail.find(
    '{%s}ApiExceptionFault' % self._GetBindingNamespace())
```

`bytes.find()` is called with a `str` argument, causing the `ValueError` you experience.

I'd argue that `zeep.wsdl.utils.etree_to_string()` should be adjusted to actually return a `str` instead of `bytes`. You could try opening an issue on Zeep's Github repository.